# How Kendo ui mvc excel export to same file for multiple grids?

Tags: javascript, promise, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have multiple (15-20) grids in my asp.net mvc project view like following.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<IssuesViewModel>()
    .Name("issues")
    .BindTo(Model.Issues)
    .Events(e=>e.ExcelExport("excelexport")
    .Columns(......)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax().ServerOperations(false)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.ID))
    )
)

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WorkigIremsViewModel>()
    .Name("working")
    .BindTo(Model.WorkingItems)
    .Events(e=>e.ExcelExport("excelexport")
    .Columns(......)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax().ServerOperations(false)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p=>p.ID))
    )
)

..
..
```

All grid has same excel export event. I am using this example https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/blob/master/grid/miltiple-grid-excel/KendoUIMVC5/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

So my javascript is like this:

```
<script>

  var promises = [ ];
  var sheets = [];

  $("#export").click(function(e){

    var workbookNames = [];
    
    if($("#issues").data("kendoGrid")){
        promises.push($.Deferred())
        workbookNames.push("issues");
        $("#issues").data("kendoGrid").saveAsExcel();
    }
    if($("#working").data("kendoGrid")){
        promises.push($.Deferred())
        workbookNames.push("works");
        $("#working").data("kendoGrid").saveAsExcel();
    }
    ..
    ..
    ..
    

    $.when.apply(null, promises)
     .then(function() {

      $.each(arguments, function(index, value){
        sheets.push(value.sheets[0]);
      });
      
      $.each(sheets, function(index, value){
        value.title = workbookNames[index];
      })

      var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
        sheets: sheets
      });


      kendo.saveAs({
        dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(),
        fileName: "Excel.xlsx"
      })
    });
  });
  
  function excelexport(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    promises[???].resolve(e.workbook);
  }
  
</script>
```

I could not resolve which promise resolve.

excelexport function is a problem for me.

```
  function excelexport(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    promises[???].resolve(e.workbook);
  }
```

How can I do this? I need a dynamic solution like this.

Comment: As you said, each grid is using the same `excelexport` function. However, the example you linked to is using a different function for each grid. In the example, the order for `promises` is known ahead of time. `promises[0]` is assigned to the Products grid, `promises[1]` is assigned to the Orders grid and so on. I would do the same for your code.

Comment: @ShawnOrr, but my grid orders may change by search results. For example, first search result may include 3 grids and other serach may iclure 10 grids.